# Entrada de dados sendo pulada após build do algoritmo

Tags: c

Meu código é bastante simples e a sua funcionalidade é a seguinte:

> - **a)** Pedir nome do Usuário
> - **b)** Pedir idade do Usuário
> - **c)** Exibir as mesmas

Porém, após o algoritmo ser **compilado e rodado**, ao dar entrada com o primeiro dado **(nome do usuário)** o executável **"pula"** a **próxima entrada de dados (idade do usuário)**.

Segue abaixo o código-fonte

```
int main(){
    char name;
    int age;

    printf("Seja bem-vindo ao nosso sistema. \n\n");
    printf("Qual o seu nome?");
    scanf(" %s", name);

    printf("Qual é a sua idade?");
    scanf(" %d", &age);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Bom como você lê e não faz nada com o que foi lido então o programa apenas encerra normalmente. Além disso você definiu sua variável name como tento um único caractere e não como uma string que se esperaria para um nome.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder armazenar mais de um carácter você precisa criar e iniciar um vetor com um tamanho pré-determinado. **(Isto para o seu caso, pois é simples e você é iniciante)**

Então antes de eu te dar a resposta de seu algoritmo, você deve estudar os seguintes conteúdos básicos para desenvolver na **linguagem c**:

> - Introdução a Linguagem C
> - Operadores e Variáveis
> - Funções
> - Funções básicas de I/O (entrada/saída)
> - Estruturas Condicionais, Laços e  Controle de fluxo
> - Blocos e Funções
> - Instruções inline e o compilador C
> - Vetores / Matrizes
> - Definição e manipulação de strings
> - Definição de string
> - Ponteiros / Parâmetros por referência
> - Operadores e tipos especiais

Agora.. Respondendo a sua questão...

O seu algoritmo deve ficar deste jeito:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char name[0];
    int age;


    printf("Entre com o seu Nome: ");
    gets(name);

    printf("Entre com a sua Idade: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("\nNOME: %s\n", name);
    printf("IDADE: %d\n", age);

    return 0;
}
```

Para subir de nível em sua carreira de desenvolvedor, sugiro estudar bastante os tópicos citados e no seu caso como você está iniciando, abaixo eu deixo um link onde contém do básico ao avançado para você entender o que eu fiz e aprender a **linguagem c**:

> **DOCUMENTAÇÃO:** [APRENDENDO A PROGRAMAR EM C](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C)

Answer (score 0):

Para entrar com um palavra e preciso criar um vetor de char, pois em C não existe o tipo String

```
char nome[100];
```

e para entrar com o nome use o comando gets() em vez de usar o scanf()

```
gets(name);
```